# dynamically creating tile with Kendo tileLayout

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I'm working on creating a MVC app and will want to specifically use Kendo's TileLayout.

The goal is to pass a ViewModel to my View, and create the Tiles based on the data.

As example, let's say I have a VM that looks like this:

This is what my ViewModel (and Controller look like)

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var viewM = new ViewModel
        {
            Items = GetItems(),
            Cats = GetCat()
        };

        return View(viewM);
    }

    public List<Item> GetItems()
    {
        var items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item() { Id = 1, Name = "Item 1", CatId = 7 });
        items.Add(new Item() { Id = 1, Name = "Item 2", CatId = 7 });
        items.Add(new Item() { Id = 2, Name = "Item 3", CatId = 10 });

        return items;
    }

    public List<Cat> GetCat()
    {
        var cat = new List<Cat>();

        cat.Add(new Cat() { CatId = 7, CatName = "Cat A" });
        cat.Add(new Cat() { CatId = 10, CatName = "Cat B" });

        return cat;
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
        public List<Cat> Cats = new List<Cat>();

    }
   
    public class Cat
    {
        public int CatId { get; set; }
        public string CatName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }

        public int CatId { get; set; }
    }
```

//I know best practice would be to store the Models in Models folder, but this is for testing purposes only

Now in my view I would expect the following layout with Kendo's TileLayout

Essentially, I would want to have a Tile for each `Cat` and within each Cat tile, I would want to have the Items with that `CatId`

```
 ------------------  ---------------
 |Cat A            | | Cat B        |
 |Item 1   Item 2  | | Item 3       |
 ------------------  ---------------
```

I'm able to create a Tile for each Cat, however I have no clue how I'd be able to include the Items in each respective Cat tile.

See below code:

```
@(
        Html.Kendo().TileLayout()
                .Name("tilelayout")
                .Columns(3)
                .RowsHeight("120px")
                .ColumnsWidth("33%")
                .Containers(c =>
                {
                    
                    foreach (var cat in Model.Cats)
                    {
                        c.Add()
                        .ColSpan(1).RowSpan(1)
                        .Header(h => h.Text(cat.CatName))
                        .BodyTemplateId("items");

                    }
                })
                .Reorderable(true)
                .Resizable(true)
                .Deferred()
       )
```

I haven't a clue how to set up the BodyTemplate or BodyTemplateId so that my items can show in each Cat. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the body template for each tile, but the `BodyTemplateId` will take only the templateId as a parameter and you cannot pass the data for the template.

If you use jQuery initialization you can serialize the model, set a function that will return the body template and use it to pass data to the template, [for example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/GxYyYqYX20nxlXTW10):

```
    @functions{
        public class Cat
        {
            public int CatId { get; set; }
            public string CatName { get; set; }
            public List<Item> Items {get; set; }
        }
        public class Item
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }

            public int CatId { get; set; }
        }
    }

    @{
        var data = Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(x=> new Cat()
        {
            CatId=x,
            CatName = "Cat "+x,
            Items = Enumerable.Range(x,7).Select(y=>new Item(){Id=x*y,Name="item "+ x*y}).ToList()
        });
    }
    <script id="tileTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <h3>Name: #=CatName#</h3>
        #=Items.map(x=>x.Name).join(', ') #
    </script>

    <div id="tilelayout"></div>

    <script>
        $("document").ready(function(){
            var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(data));
            var containers = [];
            for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                containers.push({
                    colSpan: 1,
                    rowSpan: 1,
                    bodyTemplate: function(){
                        var template = kendo.template($("#tileTemplate").html())
                        return template(data[i])
                    },
                    header:{text:data[i].CatName}
                })
            }
            $("#tilelayout").kendoTileLayout({
                containers:containers,
                columns:3
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: thank you. I'm trying to get this to work, but not in Jquery